# In a while loop, whenever a condition is fulfilled, change a certain parameter inside the loop

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a while loop in which I want to multiply the parameter "rate" by 2 anytime "fitval" is assigned the same value more than 3 times (iterations) in a row.
Fitval can take values 1,2,3,4 and 5 randomly in each iteration.

For example, if fitval is assigned the same value twice, but the third time it becomes a new value, I want the counter to "reset", so that we need 3 iterations after another again before "rate" is doubled.

I wrote a code that seems to do the trick, see below. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of implementing this however. Any tips would be appreciated!

```
i=2;
k=1;
rate=0.5;
fitval=[nan];

while i<15
    fitval=[fitval;randi(5)];

    if fitval(i)==fitval(i-1)
        k=k+1;
    else
        k=1;
    end
    if k==3
        rate=2*rate;
    end 
    i=i+1;
end
fitval
rate
```

Comment: What is your issue, errors? Your code seems to be working... this site is not for code optimization

Comment: You could generate the random array before the while loop, and then you just search for 3 similar values. That would make it simpler.

Comment: The code can be condensed a bit, but that's more a job for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, but this is slightly more compact, if this is what you are looking for:

```
while i<15
    fitval(end+1) = randi(5);
    if length(fitval) >= 3 && ...
            all(fitval(end) == [fitval(end-1), fitval(end-2)])
        rate=2*rate;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks like what you are doing is fine. Since you need to know if the same value has been given 3 times in a row, it's only natural that you have to count them. No way around it.

If you really want to be picky, I can suggest things:

Just a matter of style, but I'd replace the

```
fitval=[fitval;randi(5)];
if fitval(i)==fitval(i-1)
```

With

```
newValue = randi(5);
fitval=[fitval;newvalue];
if(newValue == fitval(i-1))
```

It's not more efficient, but it'd be more easy to read, I think (I like having one singular instruciton by line).

Also, since you know in advance the final length of fitval, you probably should declare it at creation, to allocate space once and for all. It's certainly more efficient (but also it doesn't matter for only 15 iterations).

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. In the real example the final length of fitval is not know, the code runs until I terminate it with while 1=1. I posted a condensed, simplified version here. Again, thanks for your respone!

Comment: Sorry, I usually don't downvote an answer, but this is bad and in a way even wrong.

Comment: In the first part you state that it is needed to have a counter. This is wrong, an if statement with multiple conditions can be used, and a counter won't be needed then. Second part, you make the code 'more readable'. This is as you said yourself preference, but to me you're making it a lot less readable. But as mentioned this is preference. However, OP asks to make it more elegant, which usually means shorter without unneeded redundancies. Introducing a new, unnessecary variable seems to serve the opposite purpose.

Comment: Also if you want to address someone, make sure to tag them. I read this only because I forgot to close my browser. So if I did close it, I would've never known you asked me a question.